# sympy mignotte_bound and ring

Tags: sympy, ring

I' am trying to compare the results of *dup_zz_mignotte_bound(f, K)* with some other bounds but i fail to use variable x in all of my bounds when i add the dup_zz_mignotte_bound. For example:

```
from sympy.polys import ring, ZZ
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import factor

R, x = ring('x', ZZ)

poly =  x**8 +8*x**7 +47*x**6 +136*x**5 +285*x**4 +171*x**3 - 20*x**2 - 21*x+2

print(factor(poly, x)) # this is an example of a function which is used in other bounds

p = R.dup_zz_mignotte_bound(poly) #Sympys function

print(p)
```

This returns an error when trying to call factor(). How can i use both functions?
Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My professor gave the following answer, where he manipulates the function `dup_zz_mignotte_bound` accordingly by importing it firstly from sympy. This is the correct solution by means we do not destruct x with the `ring()` function. So the solution is:

```
from sympy.polys.factortools import dup_zz_mignotte_bound
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import factor, Poly, ZZ

poly =  x**8 +8*x**7 +47*x**6 +136*x**5 +285*x**4 +171*x**3 - 20*x**2 - 21*x+2

print(factor(poly, x), '\n') # this is an example of a function which is used in other bounds

p = dup_zz_mignotte_bound(Poly(poly).all_coeffs(), ZZ) #Sympys function

print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `poly` object you create using the ring variable comes out as a polynomial object, a `PolyElement`, which does not constitutes an expression in `sympy`.

`factor` however, expects an expression. The good news are you can turn the polynomial into an expression easily (and you shouldn't send `x` as an argument):

```
>>> factor(poly.as_expr())
(x**4 + 4*x**3 + 15*x**2 + 3*x - 2)*(x**4 + 4*x**3 + 16*x**2 + 9*x - 1)
```